# How to do a minimum width for websites that uses relative (%) widths compatible with IE6+?

Tags: css

I've a website that I use percentages (%) for widths to do a flexible webiste. The problem is that in a X width (like 800px) all brokes.

There is anyway to block at 800px and then show scrollbars? I wish that you understand me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `min-width` property but it [doesn't work in IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

A workaround that I have seen is incorporate a transparent, 1px high, 800px wide image into the page that will keep the container always at a minimum of 800 pixels no matter how much the page is shrunk.

Comment: uhmm.. nice tip. I din't know it. Like put an image as a footer, no? I'll try that! nice one! :)

Comment: Perhaps the [Min-Height Fast Hack](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/) would be a better solution?

Comment: @thirtydot: im looking for min-width :P

Comment: @udexter: The same trick works for `min-height`, `min-width` and more.

Comment: @udexter the hack is likely to work for min-width as well. @thirtydot maybe, I don't have experience with it. Probably worth an answer of its own?